# Edit file that is uploaded to dropbox in Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php, dropbox-sdk

I have a file that is uploaded on dropbox i just want to edit it from my android application. I don't want to download it. File is in form of json formate. E.g I have a file name "Add"
Formate :

```
{"slots":[       {"slotid":"2b","updatetime":1477650798,"active":true,"adurl":"https:\/\/play.goo    gle.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=com.MoversGames.DriftCarSimulatorExtremeDriving","imgurl":"https://i.imgur.com/oRHNKN0.jpg","hd":"false","x":0,"y":0},
{"slotid":"1a","updatetime":1477650727,"active":true,"adurl":"https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=com.MoversGames.RCCarRacing","imgurl":"https://i.imgur.com/sF5IrDe.jpg","hd":"false","x":0,"y":0}],"containers":[]}
```

Is is uploaded on dropbox. I just want to edit it through my android application.

**Note:I want to edit it online from my android application**

Answer (score 0):

To use the Dropbox API from Android, you should use [the Dropbox API v2 Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java). There's [an example Android app here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android).

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to directly edit specific pieces of files on Dropbox; you need to just upload the entire new version, e.g., using [the `upload` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#upload-java.lang.String-).